# Going up one dir in NERDTree keeping the old root open, together with all its open children, recursively

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

I do this,

```
$ tree
.
├── dir1
│   ├── dir11
│   │   └── hello
│   └── dir12
│       └── hello
└── dir2
    ├── dir21
    │   └── hello
    └── dir22
        └── hello
$ cd dir1/dir11
$ vim
```

then I open NERDTree, and see it shows

```
  [  ]hello
```

then I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> ***twice***, and NERDTree shows this:

```
▾ [  ]dir1/
  ▸ [  ]dir11/
  ▸ [  ]dir12/
▸ [  ]dir2/
```

whereas I expected this:

```
▾ [  ]dir1/
  ▾ [  ]dir11/
      [  ]hello
  ▸ [  ]dir12/
▸ [  ]dir2/
```

Unless someone tells me it has always worked the former way, I'm pretty sure I relied on it working the latter way.

**EDIT**:

When I'm in the NERDTree window, `:map U` gives back this:

```
n  U           *@:call nerdtree#ui_glue#invokeKeyMap("U")<CR>
```

Comment: Probably the NERDTree maintainers would know

Comment: Works the way you expect for me. In fact the help says "Like |NERDTree-u| except that the old tree root is kept open." So, if I'm reading that right, you would have to have overridden the default behavior to NOT see 'hello'. It's like you are actually using `u`. Are you sure you are using all default settings?

Comment: An example of a setting that might inhibit expected behavior is NerdTreeShowFiles (mapped to `F`), i.e. to demonstrate directly you can hit `F` then `UU` (not saying you did that, just demonstrating how it would replicate your unexpected result). Check all mappings and settings is my final comment for now. :)

Comment: @BLayer, no the result I get and show in the question is not what I would obtain by using `u`, but the one I'd get by using `uU`. I'll check the mappings, however.

Comment: However, @BLayer, you're right, I've commented out all NERDTree-related things in my vimrc and the expected behavior is recovered. I'll now check what is the culprit.

Comment: Kind of nitpicking, no? :) Besides, I didn't mean just `u` alone, of course, I meant it was as if one of the `U`s was replaced with `u`.

Comment: Well, I wanted to make sure the description is accurate and understood. However, look at what strange thing I've found....

Comment: Yeah, there's no way in hell I would have guessed THAT one. Sounds like someone might not be using key map scoping appropriately in their plugin.

Comment: Or something along those lines....I'm not familiar with vim-devicons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by BLayer in the comments, the problem comes from the settings.

However, it's not a NERDTree setting, but a vim-devicons setting which breaks the <kbd>U</kbd> command of NERDTree!

Indeed, this is the culprit in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
let g:DevIconsEnableFoldersOpenClose = 1
```

This setting is meant to use a special symbol for open folder, and it works, in that sense. However I have to comment it to take advantage of NERDTree's `U` mapping.

I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons/issues/365).